# Obtain Product List with detail from order id in Prestashop with MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop, product, orders

Im new in Prestashop ,i want to  get the details of products from the id order from the data base so can anyone help me with the mysql query .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use PrestaShop classes instead of mysql query:

```
    $order = new Order($id_order);
    $details = $order->getProductsDetail();
    d($details);
```

Comment: $order = new Order($id_order);    $order->current_state = your_status;    $order->save();